# Wear TileService Lifecycle

Tags: android, wear-os, tile-service

I have created a [TileService](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/wear/tiles/TileService) for watch app. When i switch to my `TileService` every time `onCreate` method is called multiple times (3 or 4 times).

As `TileService` is a `Service` why `onCreate` is called multiple times?

And when I switch to my `TileService` by swiping it doesn't call `onTileRequest` for every `onCreate` to update UI.

From official doc `onTileRequest` called every time user have a action on UI.

Can anyone explain me the lifecycle of `TileService` .

How can i update Tile UI every time `onCreate` is called ?

I need latest UI when user switch to the Tile by swiping.

Answer (score 3):

Try using onTileEnterEvent. It's called every time the tile is visible.

A simple example that causes the Tile to render a new UI.

```
override fun onTileEnterEvent(requestParams: EventBuilders.TileEnterEvent){

TileService.getUpdater(this)
            .requestUpdate(MyTileService::class.java)
}
```